# Will SonarXML supports Orbeon XFORMS namespace tags in XHTML

Tags: sonarqube, xhtml, orbeon

We are using Orbeon Forms specified namespace in XHTML. I didn't find much tools do code quality analysis for XForms.

1. Will SonarXML validate the Orbeon Forms specified namespace tags while validating?
2. If validating with SonarXML is possible, do we need to change any settings?

[image: Sample used code]

Comment: Instead of an image insert proper code.

Comment: Is this one of those libraries where they use SO as a support forum?

Comment: Ah, yes. https://www.sonarqube.org/community/feedback/

Answer (score 2):

From what I read about [SonarXML](https://docs.sonarqube.org/display/PLUG/SonarXML), it does its XML validation using a schema, so you could, in the case of XForms:

- Use the standard [XForms schema](https://www.w3.org/community/xformsusers/wiki/XForms_2.0#Schema_for_XForms_.28Non-Normative.29).
- In the context of Orbeon Forms, use a [modified version of the standard schema](https://github.com/orbeon/orbeon-forms/blob/master/src/main/resources/org/orbeon/oxf/xml/schemas/xforms-1_0-orbeon.xsd), which is maintained by Orbeon. However note that this schema is intended to be used with schema-aware editors, not for validation, so it might require further changes from you to be used in that context.

Comment: thanks for the response @avernet . Could you please suggest me a plugin which validates Orboen Forms(Highlighting or warning misuse of 'eq' or '=' or 'is', warning for 'while' instead of 'iterate' or vice versa, for 'setvalue' condition is written in action block instead inside xf:setvalue, appropriate usage of xs:integer and xs:decimal so on...). Looking for a plugin can do a basic code review and provide valid suggestions.

Comment: @eswarthammana It sounds like you'd like to validate XPath. I've personally never used SonarQube, and so don't know if a plugin that validates or gives warnings specific to XPath exists. You might have better luck asking that question specifically, independently of your use of Orbeon Forms.

Answer (score 0):

[SonarWeb](https://docs.sonarqube.org/display/PLUG/SonarWeb) can support following suffixes “.html,.xhtml,.rhtml,.shtml” 
which runs against default sonarWay 59 rules.Which will not check for Xpath violations.